# Is a custom spell that requires touching an object somatic/material based?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

Is a custom spell I would create that reinforces the structure of an object considered as a somatic or material one? I want to recreate Shirou "trace on" spell from the Fate Unlimited Blade Works series.

For example, I found a long stick. I want it to be as tough as steel, by touching it. Is the spell considered to have a somatic/material component?

Comment: As written, it is very unclear whether you understand the purpose of Somatic/Verbal/Material components within spells. Can you expand on what you understand (or think you understand) regarding those aspects of spellcasting?

Comment: Welcome to the site! While you've got a good first question, it's definitely a bit unclear (although you did get an answer that helped!) I'm not sure if you're asking how spell components work or if you're asking for a review of a [homebrew](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8171/how-should-i-ask-about-my-dd-5e-homebrew-being-balanced), but I think if you can dial that in you may get more answers that can help guide and a question that fits within the parameters of the site. If you do have questions, come join us in [chat]!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've asked slightly differing questions here; I'll try to clarify:

## 1. Spells that require you to touch the target would generally have a somatic component, and may or may not have a material component.

A spell with a somatic component just means one that requires you to have your hands free in order to cast it (in order to make some kind of required magical gestures).

A spell with a material component requires you to have one or more specific items in order to cast it. If these items aren't listed as having a GP value then many DMs will handwave them as a requirement provided that you have an arcane component pouch / arcane focus. Spells with costly material components tend to be ones that would be problematic if they were able to be cast without limits (e.g. Raise Dead, Identify) - this categorisation is pretty much independent of whether or not they require you to touch the target.

## 2. A spell that alters / reinforces the structure of the target would be better classified as a spell from the Transmutation school.

I'd recommend looking up specific examples in here to find something that you're looking for, and check the listed components for the spell in question. Pretty much all of the transmutations which do something similar to this have a Somatic and a Material component (although in many cases the material component doesn't have a listed GP cost).

Hope that helps - happy to clarify if I've misunderstood the question :)

Comment: Thank you so much ! That was exactly what i was looking for !

Comment: As a note, a spell that requires touching the target does not necessarily have a somatic component. For example, *tongues* has a range of touch (and mentions touching the target in the spell text) but has no somatic component. Presumably this means that even if you have both your hands full (and therefore cannot supply somatic components of a spell), you could still poke the target with your elbow and say the words of the spell to cast it on them.

Comment: Not all touch spells have a somatic component (you do use generally, but I don't think there's necessarily a direct correlation without a full review of all touch spells). Given that OP may be misunderstanding some spellcasting rules with regard to homebrewing plans it may have been better to help them clarify their question. On the other hand, you clearly helped:)

Comment: @NautArch - excluding XtGE, there are 75 spells with a range of Touch. Of those, only 2 (Light and Tongues) don't require a Somatic component, so I think it's fair to say 'generally' :p but yes clarification would've been better.

Comment: Very true, but the vast majority also require a V or M - so I'm not sure concluding that the S is for 'touching' is relevant because you could equally conclude that V or M are just as important. I think OP's issue is more about misunderstanding spell components but without their clarification we're just guessing (which we try not to do...but you did guess correctly for them, but I do worry that you also gave misleading information)

Comment: @NautArch - Noted, will ask for more clarification in future :)